# Three js transparency issue with PointClouds and textures

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, transparency

I have two PointCloud objects, each for a specific structure and texture. One should be clickable but not the other. Let's call them *P1* and *P2*, respectively.

*P1* is initialized using a THREE.ShaderMaterial as:

```
var p1Material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    attributes: attributes,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent,
    transparent: true
});
```

*P2* in it's turn is using a THREE.PointCloudMaterial as:

```
var p2Material = THREE.PointCloudMaterial({
    size : SIZE,
    map : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("icons/myAwesomeIcon.png"),
    sizeAttenuation : true,
    transparent: true
});
```

Both resulting THREE.PointCloud objects have their ***sortParticles*** property set to *true*.

However, I'm running into transparency issues such as the following:

(REMOVED - LOOK AT EDIT)

Everything is a texture, except for the white line. The Sphere texture is used in *P2*, and the other textures in *P1*.

We can see that *P2*'s textures are not really transparent against *P1*'s. But they are, against each other, as seen on the second image. Inversly, the same is happening on between *P1*'s textures. However, here's a different example, in the same scene:

(REMOVED - LOOK AT EDIT)

Some of *P1*'s textures are ok, but *P2*'s don't want to behave properly.

I suspect having the textures reside in different PointClouds is not helping. Yet, since the *P2*'s elements shouldn't be clickable, for performance reasons I decided to separate them from the lot, and thus having *P1* and *P2*. Note that selectability is done by clicking on something and using a THREE.Raycaster.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong guys?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Apparently the problem seems to be due to using BufferGeometry...

Here are two JSFiddle sources that are exactly the same, except for the used geometry.

http://jsfiddle.net/vf6uu90t/3/

http://jsfiddle.net/2uh0q8Lr/2/

Am I missing something?

I had to remove the links from before, because stackoverflow only allows me to insert two links... --'

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code? Helping would be much easier

Comment: I'm setting something up in JS fiddle.

Comment: JSFiddle example is up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the ThreeJs github issue, and a possible solution.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5668

The trick was alphaTesting. In any case, there seems to be a bug related to this is r69.